# Updating textbox fill color using DocumentFormat.OpenXml from VB.Net

Tags: openxml

I have a request where I need to update a textbox fill color and border where specific text is found.

the following is part of my code.

```
   For Each shape As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing In mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants.OfType(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing)()
   'Replace date stamp with current date
   'Find all placeholders that have mm/dd/yyyy as text.
      If shape.Descendants.OfType(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text).Count() > 0 Then
         If shape.Descendants.OfType(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text).First().InnerText = "mm/dd/yyyy" Then
            LogVerboseMessage("Updating all date placeholders within document to current date")
            Dim curDate As Date = Date.Now()
            Dim curDateOnly As Date = curDate.Date

            LogVerboseMessage("Shape has been found!  Prepare to replace date.")
            shape.Descendants.OfType(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text).First().Text = curDateOnly.ToString()
            Dim color As String = shape.Descendants.OfType(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.SolidFill).First.RgbColorModelHex.Val.ToString()

      End If End If Next
```

When I run the above code in debug mode I get

> "Sequence contains no elements"

error message.

I need to be able to get the current value and update it to a new value.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What line is causing the error to be raised? One thing to consider is that quite a bit of color assignment etc. is effected via the style hierarchy, meaning a value is inherited from a placeholder or theme. It's a common case that an element like fill or RGBColor will not explicitly exist, indicating its value should be inherited from the nearest source in its style hierarchy.

Comment: Dim color As String = shape.Descendants.OfType(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.SolidFill).First.RgbColorModelHex.Val.ToString() is the line throwing the error.

Comment: Yep, makes sense then. The `solidFill` element can be empty and often is. It can also contain a schemeColor element rather than an RGBColor element (you'll need to look up exact spelling), and perhaps more frequently does since it's common to use theme colors rather than hard-coded RGB values. You could add a 'getOrAddRgbColor()' function that checks and returns the RGB bit if it's there and adds or changes to one otherwise.